# Changing exposure of jpeg

Tags: image-processing, graphics, image-manipulation

Given a jpeg, what is the formula to change the exposure of that jpeg by +/-1 stop or as known as 1 EV? I want to simulate this exposure change. Is there a formula/ method to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I can demonstrate that using ImageMagick, which is included in most Linux distros and available for OSX and Windows from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

First, at the Terminal command line create an image:

```
convert -size 512x512 gradient:black-yellow gradient.png
```

[image]

Now, the way to effect `+1 stop` exposure increase is to composite the image with itself using the `Screen` blending mode - it is available in Photoshop and ImageMagick and is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes).

So, the formula to composite image `A` with image `B` is:

```
1-stop brighter image = 1-(1-A)(1-B)
```

but as we are compositing the image with itself, `A` and `B` are the same, so we effectively have

```
1-(1-A)(1-A)
```

ImageMagick refers to the pixels of an image using `p` rather than `A`, so we can do a 1-stop increase like this:

```
convert gradient.png -colorspace RGB -fx "(1-(1-p)(1-p))" result.png
```

Note that the Wikipedia article, and ImageMagick's `-fx` both assume your pixel intensities vary between `0` and `1.0`. If you are using 8-bit images, you should calculate with `255` in place of `1`, namely

```
+1 stop brighter image = 255-(255-A)(255-A)
```

or if using 16-bit values

```
+1 stop brighter image = 65535-(65535-A)(65535-A)
```

The above `fx`-based method is however, very slow because the `-fx` is interpreted rather than compiled, so a faster way to do it is:

```
convert gradient.png gradient.png -colorspace RGB -compose screen -composite screen.png
```

Just for fun, another way of looking at that is that we take the inverse of `A`, that is 1-A, and square it, and then take the inverse, so it can be done like this:

```
convert gradient.png -colorspace RGB -negate -evaluate pow 2 -negate result.png
```

[image]

The equivalent of `-1 stop` exposure decrease is to composite the image with itself using the `Multiply` blend mode, the formula being

```
1-stop darker image = A x B
```

which you would do faster with

```
convert gradient.png gradient.png -colorspace RGB -compose multiply -composite result.png
```

or even faster, by using memory-to-memory cloning rather than reading from disk twice, with

```
convert gradient.png -colorspace RGB +clone -compose multiply -composite result.png
```

but could do equally with

```
convert gradient.png -colorspace RGB -evaluate pow 2 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better to use linear light, I think. Changing one f-stop doubles (or halves) the number of photons captured, so I think you want `out = (2 * in ^ gamma) ^ (1 / gamma)`, where `gamma` is roughly 2.4 for sRGB. If you don't gamma/ungamma, you will boost (or reduce) contrast when you do your neat compose-with-itself hack.

Comment: @user894763 Thank you for your thoughts. I suspect you are right but I'm not sure on how to implement that in ImageMagick... would I be correct if I convert the input images to RGB colorpsace after reading in but before processing?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes, I think so. `-colorspace RGB` at the start of processing, then `-colorspace sRGB` at the end. You might not need the second one, does `convert` do that for you automatically? I'm unsure.

Comment: @user894763 Thanks again for your inputs - I think I have updated correctly for linear gamma processing, and yes, I believe IM will convert automagically to sRGB on writing out.

Comment: I tried this with several photographs, and it _does not actually work_. There are color and contrast shifts which are not the same as changing the exposure (say, by altering ISO) by one stop in camera.